# Flutter Hive hot-restart type-cast error when i try to retrieve data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I store some data in the hive box .. then retrieve it in FavoritesPage it works perfectly
but when I hot-restart the app and go to the FavoritesPage it throws a type-cast error

FavoritesPage :

```
class _FavoritesPageState extends State<FavoritesPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //HandleFavorites.deleteAll();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ValueListenableBuilder<Box<List<FavoritesSongs>>>(
        valueListenable: HandleFavorites.getFavoritesSongs().listenable(),
        builder: (context, fav, _) {
          final favorites = fav.values.toList().cast<List<FavoritesSongs>>();
          return favorites.isEmpty
              ? const Center(child: Text('No Sounds Yet'))
              : Column(
                  children: favorites.map((e) => buildContent(e)).toList());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

buildContent :

```
Widget buildContent(List<FavoritesSongs> favoritesSongs) {
  if (favoritesSongs.isEmpty) {
    return const Center(child: Text('Empty'));
  } else {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: favoritesSongs.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final fav = favoritesSongs[index];
            return Text(fav.id);
          },
        ),
        const Divider(
          height: 20,
          thickness: 2,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

HandleFavorites class :

```
class HandleFavorites {
static Box<List<FavoritesSongs>> getFavoritesSongs() =>
      Hive.box<List<FavoritesSongs>>(StaticWords.favorites);
}
```

favorites class

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'favorites_songs.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1, adapterName: "FavoritesSongsAdapter")
class FavoritesSongs {
  FavoritesSongs({required this.id, required this.volume});

  @HiveField(0)
  String id;

  @HiveField(1)
  double volume;
}

@HiveType(typeId: 2, adapterName: "FavoritesListAdapter")
class FavoritesList extends HiveObject {
  FavoritesList({required this.listId, required this.listOfSounds});

  @HiveField(0)
  String listId;

  @HiveField(1)
  List<FavoritesSongs> listOfSounds;
}
```

how i init hive
main.dart file

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(FavoritesSongsAdapter());
  Hive.openBox<List<FavoritesSongs>>(StaticWords.favorites);
  runApp(const Equable());
}
```

when i go to the favoritesPage it throw this error

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following _CastError was thrown building
> ValueListenableBuilder<Box<List>>(dirty, state:
> _ValueListenableBuilderState<Box<List>>#b8b8b):
> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

Comment: Show your FavoritesSongs class.

Comment: i did update my code including my favorites class